# React Router <Link />

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use react router's  like this:

```
<Link
 key={key}
 to={link.url}
>
 {link.label}
</Link>
```

value of
`link.url` is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/articles/list?page=1`
so when I click on the `<Link/>` my app goes to href `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/articles/http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/articles/list?page=1`
How to do that correctly? In the href should be only: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/articles/list?page=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The react router `Link`component is intended to only be used for internal navigation.